# How to add "get_theme_mod" inside a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I want to make dynamic the content inside a shortcode so I can modify it in the customizer. I created the customizer tabs. Now, I want to create a shortcode to place it anywhere in the page while being able to manipulate in the customizer.

This is the code I'm working on. Thanks!

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: ....
 */

// Exit if accessed directly
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
    exit;
  }

function customizer_inject_css()
{
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        :root {

            --theme-page-width: <?php echo get_theme_mod('theme_page_width', '1366px');
            ?>!important;
        }

        .stm-template-car_dealer_two .container {
            max-width: var(--theme-page-width)!important;
        }
    </style>


<?php
}



add_shortcode( 'ui_gallery','function_gallery_shortcode' );
function function_gallery_shortcode(){
    $dynamic_h1 = "<h1>" . get_theme_mod('dymanich1') . "</h1>";
    return $dynamic_h1;
}


    add_action( 'wp_head', 'customizer_inject_css');

    add_action("customize_register","register_customizer");

    function register_customizer( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize) {

        $wp_customize->add_panel( 'theme_extension_panel',
        array(
            'priority'            => 2,
            'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
            'title'                => __('Theme Extensions'),
            'description'        => __(''),
        ) );

            $wp_customize->add_section("general_section", array(
                "title"            => __("General"),
                "priority"    => 1,
                "panel"        => "theme_extension_panel"
            ));

                $wp_customize->add_setting( 'theme_page_width', array(
                    "transport"        => "refresh",
                    "default"        => "",
                ) );
                $wp_customize->add_control(
                    new WP_Customize_Control(
                    $wp_customize,
                    'theme_page_width_control',
                    array(
                        'label'         => __(''),
                        'section'    => 'general_section',
                        'settings'   => 'theme_page_width',
                        "type"         => "text",
                        "description" => "Max Width",
                        'priority'      => 1
                    ) )
                );

               $wp_customize->add_setting( 'dynamich1', array(
                    "transport"        => "refresh",
                    "default"        => "",
                ) );
                $wp_customize->add_control(
                    new WP_Customize_Control(
                    $wp_customize,
                    'dynamich1_control',
                    array(
                        'label'         => __(''),
                        'section'    => 'general_section',
                        'settings'   => 'dynamich1',
                        "type"         => "text",
                        "description" => "display h1",
                        'priority'      => 1
                    ) )
                );

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would comment, but lack the pointage...
You seem to be on the right track:

I see that your shortcode callback and the function are named
    differently:  (*`f_gallery_shortcode`* / *`function_gallery_shortcode`*).

Try this:

```
add_shortcode( 'ui_gallery','function_gallery_shortcode' );
function function_gallery_shortcode(){
    $dynamic_h1 = "<h1>" . get_theme_mod('dynamich1') . "</h1>";
    return $dynamic_h1;
}
```

now using `[ui_gallery]` in your posts, should return the results of your Customizer value `<h1>dymanich1</h1>`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work, but its good to know I'm in a good track

Comment: I just tested the code on my end and it works perfectly, it even insert <h1></h1> if the setting is not set. Are you sure you have named the settings correctly in both code sections?

Comment: In the customizer code the setting is named dynamich1, in the shortcode it was named dymanich1. I have updated my codeblock to 'dynamich1'.

Comment: Hello Sir!!!! Wow, that was epic, I've been trying to figure it out for 3 days, my head hurts, but now thanks to your help I'm ready to move on. Thank you so much for take your time and help me out!!!!! ;)